# Type Traits check OF CRTP Derived , in base class ,issue is undefined type

Tags: c++, templates, lazy-evaluation, traits, crtp

Looking for a solution like EvalDelay below to fix undefined type issue
EvalDelay  is my attempt to solve the problem, but no work

Since traits being checked in base class of derived, derived is still undefined 
Question is how do i delay the evaluation with some template magic

The trait check is kept simple here, its just an is base of  check.

```
 struct Base{};

 template<class T_Type>
 struct T_CheckTrait
 {
    static const bool bVal = std::is_base_of_v<Base, T_Type>;   
  };

template<class TypeToDelay, class T = Next> 
struct EvalDelay
{
    //using type = std::add_volatile<TypeToDelay>;      
    //using type = typename type_identity<TypeToDelay>::type;

    using type = TypeToDelay;
};

 template<class T_Derived>
 struct RexBase
  {
       using T_TypeDly = typename EvalDelay<T_Derived>::type;
       static const bool bVal = T_CheckTrait<T_TypeDly>::bVal;
  };


  struct Rex:RexBase<Rex>{   };

void Main 
    {
    Rex Obj; //and on compilation i get error undefined type, not here but in templates above    

    }
```

Does not compile cause am trying to check traits of Rex in its base class at compile time.

Looking for template magic to delay the evaluation

std::add_volatile does delay evaluation as shown in EvalDelay, but it delays it till run time, looking  for compile time evaluation but delayed.

Thanks

Comment: Evaluation of what? What is your actual problem you are trying to solve? What is `Next`? Please, create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your end goal is, but here's how to delay evaluation of a type trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base {};

template<class T>
struct EvalDelay
{
    using type = T;
};

template<class T_Derived>
struct RexBase
{
    using is_base = typename EvalDelay<std::is_base_of<Base, T_Derived>>::type;
};

struct Rex : RexBase<Rex> {   };
struct Rex2 : RexBase<Rex2>, Base {   };

int main()
{
    Rex Obj;
    static_assert(Rex::is_base::value == false, "Rex is not Base");
    static_assert(Rex2::is_base::value == true, "Rex2 is Base");
}
```

[Live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/yL1mNw)